# After reinstallation, getting "localhost redirected you too many times" error

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I created a docker container from a dockerfile on port `8080` that I was able to visit via `localhost:8080`. Then, I stopped and removed the container using `container stop mycontainer` and `container rm mycontainer`. I then removed the corresponding image.

I then reinstalled the docker container from another directory on my local machine. Everything installed as I had expected, but I'm now getting this error:

> localhost redirected you too many times.
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I've cleared cookies and browsing data which hasn't helped. It appears from the NGINX logs that the server is sending a circular 302 redirect to itself.

I'm using the exact same configuration as I was the first time I created the container. Is it possible that the initial build that I believe was deleted is now interfering with my current build?

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
pid             /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        client_max_body_size 4M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

`nginx.error.log` is empty. `nginx.access.log` provides this documentation of the 403 error:

> 172.17.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2017:01:56:46 +0000] "GET /www/admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone down the line, the issue was in the permissions of my PHP files. To diagnose, I realized that `index.php` and `install.php` were redirecting back and forth to each other. It appears that `install.php` was failing because the nginx user, www-data, was unable to install properly. I changed permissions from 644 to 700 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering because I don't have the reputation points to comment.

For debugging, you might want to add the
    `tail /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log` error logs to the question.

I'm wondering if you have an HTML file in the root `/var/www/html` folder because the Apache defaults would be in another folder.

Comment: Thanks - there's nothing in the error log and added the 302 from the access log. I like the idea that the html file could have caused it but alas that isn't the case.